# how to fix leaks with instruments in iOS app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, hypothesis-test

I have just started with instruments to find for memory leaks in app Can any one suggest me how to fix the leaks as mentioned in instruments..

Actually I am getting as shown below screen

[image]

Can any one suggest me the steps to fix..

I have referred here:  [Instruments and debugging](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Jea8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA469&lpg=PA469&dq=how+to+check+the+battery+performance+for+an+ios+app+using+instruments&source=bl&ots=VRB_6rlOOb&sig=Y3P9x7xg-U_PeHMyau9NRuAjSm4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBmoVChMIjI7rh6H0yAIVQh-UCh3LnwWg#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20check%20the%20battery%20performance%20for%20an%20ios%20app%20using%20instruments&f=false) but could not fix this..

Here it has suggested to create hypothesis to estimate time consumption..Does any one know how to create this?

```
  -(void)ShowingDeals
  {
     @try {
    CLLocationManager *lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [lm location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;

    NSString *strLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coord.latitude];
    NSString *strLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coord.longitude];
    [[SharedData userInfo]setObject:strLat forKey:@"lat"];
    [[SharedData userInfo]setObject:strLong forKey:@"long"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",[strLat floatValue], [strLong floatValue]];
    NSError* error;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

    NSData *data = [locationString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *arrResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSDictionary *dic =[NSDictionary dictionary];
    if (arrResults.count>0) {
       dic = [[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray* arr = [dic objectForKey:@"address_components"];
    //Iterate each result of address components - find locality and country
    NSString *cityName;
    NSString *countryName;


   // NSString* locationFinal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",cityName,countryName];
    [[SharedData userInfo]setObject:cityName forKey:@"City"];

    max=max+1;

    _collectionView.alpha=1.0;
    _activity.alpha=1.0;
    [_activity startAnimating];
    if (myTaskBool==YES) {
        myTaskBool=NO;
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myTask) withObject:self];
    }

     NSDictionary *userInfo = [SharedData userInfo];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    });





}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception);
}
@finally {

  }
}
```

Comment: please show the code of `[self ShowingDeals]` method

Comment: @Varun Naharia, Updated my question please check this once

Comment: go to `[self ShowingDeals]` through instruments and their you will see same red marking in that method that is responsible for this, by viewing code it all looks good but there is one more method that needs to be review that is   `[ZagHttpClient postDataToURL ...];`